# Meteor Publish + Reactive query object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Consider the following:

On my client I build a complex filter, which is held in a custom reactive object called `currentFilter`.

`currentFilter.buildQuery()` returns the object which I use to query the mongodb database.

Because of the amount of data in the mongodb database on the server, I want to filter the data on the server side, and publish only what is needed to the client.

My code is as follows:

```
//CLIENT

// file = a.html

<template name="myTemplate">
  {{data}}
</template>

//file = a.js

cbs = new Mongo.Collection('cbsLoc');

Template.myTemplate.helpers({

    data: function () {
        Tracker.autorun(function () {
            Meteor.subscribe('cbsLoc',currentFilter.buildQuery())

        });

        return cbs.find()    // (a)
    }
})

//SERVER

Meteor.publish('cbsLoc', function(filter) {
    return cbs.find(filter)
});
```

The `cbs.find()` will return data to populate a table. Unfortunately it doesn't work. While the data does get returned to the client, it isn't displayed in the dom.

It works perfectly however (ie it does get displayed in the dom) if I change the line at `(a)` to `cbs.find().fetch()`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given the template anything much to help it display the data. You've just given it a single object called 'data'. What's in that 'data' object? Are there lots of records or just one? What does a cbs record have in it? What exactly do you want to display? You say it works perfectly however if you use fetch() - which turns a cursor into an array. What gets displayed in that case? A table? Do you mean that you're sending html markup as well in the data object? Sorry if that's a lot of questions, but you haven't actually given much information.

Comment: The more questions the better! The data I'm passing to the dom is a cursor with a number of records >1, and each record has >50 fields. In the application, {{data}} is  actually a {{> reactiveTable}} object (from the reactive table package) which handles the creation of the html table (I've tried to simplify my example). 

Given a filter created in the client, I want to display the returned filtered curser in the dom as a HTML table.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking the obvious, but was there no message in your browser console/developer tools when you just used cbs.find()?

Comment: There were no errors in the console.

When I run the following in the browser console:

`cbs.find()` returns a LocalCollection.Cursor

`cbs.find().count()` returns 35

`cbs.find().fetch()` returns the 35 objects

Comment: You should not be starting a subscription from a helper - see [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes). You should probably move all of this into a [template subscription](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've put this in an answer because there's a bit of code in it - too difficult to read in a comment.

The only thing I can think of is that in the case of the cursor it's not ready when the template displays, whereas I seem to remember that in the case of fetch() meteor will wait until everything has arrived.

Try a bit of defensive coding such as this:

```
data: function () {
   Tracker.autorun(function () {
       Meteor.subscribe('cbsLoc',currentFilter.buildQuery())
   });
   var cursor = cbs.find();
   if(cursor) 
       return cbs.find()    // (a)
}
```

If that doesn't want to work, then maybe you should move getting the data to the router (if you have iron-router), where you can put the subscribe part in the waitOn() or subscriptions() function, which in general is where subscriptions should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

I moved the subscription into an `onCreated()` callback. My final piece of code looks like this:

```
//CLIENT

// file = a.html

<template name="myTemplate">

    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" collection=cbListings settings=settings}}
    {{else}}
        {{>loading}}
    {{/if}}

</template>

//file = a.js

cbs = new Mongo.Collection('cbsLoc');

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;

    self.autorun(function () {

        self.subscribe('cbs', currFilter.buildQuery());

    });

    self.cbListings = function(){
        return cbs.find();
    }

});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({

    cbListings: function() {

        return Template.instance().cbListings();
    }
});

//SERVER

Meteor.publish('cbsLoc', function(filter) {
    return cbs.find(filter)
});
```

Thanks to David Weldon and mwarren for pointing me in the right diection.

The solution is based off the [docs here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) as well as this [blog post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/).

As an aside, this only works with the `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` like so:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" collection=cbListings settings=settings}}
{{else}}
    {{>loading}}
{{/if}}
```

To me, it's not obvious why this pattern works. My confusion lies around the relationship between the `onCreated` and `helper` callbacks:

1)

On page load, `self.cbListings` is `null` (which makes sense to me)

2)

Following this, We then have `cbListings` being created by the helper, but it's returning a reference to itself through the `Template.instance().cbListings()` code.

With the above, what's going on here?

Also, how is this not throwing an error the first time it's created as `Template.instance().cbListings()` doesn't exist yet. I know this because if I print `self.cbListings` at the `onCreated` callback the output gives me undefined. But if I do so inside `self.cbListings` I'll get an output = `function()` (I'm using firebug).

3)

Finally, although the `onCreated` callback is only run once, `Template.subscriptionsReady` is managing to do something whereby `self.cbListings = function(){return cbs.find()}` gets executed after `cbListings` is created by the `helper`. How is this happening?